# Why is the double slit experiment highly regarded as mysterious?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, observers

I read in Wikipedia:

The need for the "observer" to be conscious has been rejected by mainstream science as a misconception rooted in a poor understanding of the quantum wave function ψ and the quantum measurement process.

So it's simply an interaction between the detector and electrons that make electrons behave as particles. Even if we don't understand the interaction yet (or do we?), what's so strange about it?

Comment: I had never read anything by Feynman, he is awesome! What is his most interesting book? I'd also appreciate newer books in the same style concerning my question, since his books are more than 30 years old.